# Is it possible to get the list of all members from a discord guild using non-bot token?

Tags: api, discord, discord.py, member

Since discord developers added intents system I'm unable to get all members from guild using  token of my own account. Is it possible now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not able to get all members in a selfbot due to discord trying to stop mass dm bots.
(selfbots are agaist discord tos and can get you banned)

Comment: btw if this answer your question please mark as accepted answer

Comment: I found one solution, it is undocumented api with op code 14

Answer (score 0):

Using selfbots is against ToS, but you can use [discord.py-self](https://github.com/dolfies/discord.py-self)